# How to pass an array as an argument from pug to JS?

Tags: pug

I'm trying to pass an array `c[x].topLevelIndustry` as an argument to a function in pug, my pug code is:

```
script.
  function myFunction(z) {
    var y = document.getElementById("demo");
    y.innerHTML =z.join();
  }


   myFunction(c[x].topLevelIndustry)
   p#demo
```

c is passed via index.js, my JS code is:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'About', c:c, d:d, e:e});
```

When I pass ['banana', 'apple'] as the argument then everything works, so I suppose the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is the server-side variable that you want to pass in to your client-side Javascript:

```
const veryImportantObject = {foo: 'bar', number: 666};
```

Your're passing it into Pug as a template variable like this:

```
pug.renderFile(__dirname + '/Example.pug', {

    myPugTemplateVar: veryImportantObject,
});
```

From your Pug template, you can pass it along to the client side unescaped by using the `!{}` interpolation syntax. In order to avoid getting a useless `toString()` output like `[Object object]` or whatever, use JSON.

```
script(type="text/javascript").
    myPugTemplateVarInTheBrowser = !{JSON.stringify(myPugTemplateVar)};
```

This will output an HTML template with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myPugTemplateVarInTheBrowser = {foo: 'bar', number: 666};
</script>
```